# How to extract values with BeautifulSoup with no class

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

html code :

```
<td class="_480u">
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div>
            Female
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

I wanted the value "Female" as an output.

I tried `bs.findAll('div',{'class':'clearfix'})` ; `bs.findAll('tag',{'class':'_480u'})` 
But these classes are all over my html code and the output is a big list. I wanted to incorporate {td --> class = ".." and div --> class = ".."} in my search, so that I get the output as Female. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`stripped_strings`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) property:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
>>> html = '''<td class="_480u">
...     <div class="clearfix">
...         <div>
...             Female
...         </div>
...     </div>
... </td>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> print ' '.join(soup.find('div', {'class': 'clearfix'}).stripped_strings)
Female
>>> print ' '.join(soup.find('td', {'class': '_480u'}).stripped_strings)
Female
```

or specify class as empty string (or `None`) and use `string` property:

```
>>> soup.find('div', {'class': ''}).string
u'\n            Female\n        '
>>> soup.find('div', {'class': ''}).string.strip()
u'Female'
```

Comment: Thankyou for the quick answer. :)

Comment: @user1946217 Please be sure to mark his answer as correct if it was useful!